# R plotly add state boundaries to interactive choropleth map

Tags: r, interactive, r-plotly, choropleth

I would like to create an interactive choropleth map with R plotly, just like the example on the R-plotly choropleth map homepage: https://plotly.com/r/mapbox-county-choropleth/

I have managed to get an interactive map with my own data. However, I need to include state boundaries, overlayed over the counties and display in the legend below "colorbar" the state boundaries.

Suppose, I have my state boundaries as shapefile and converted it to geojson, similar to the counties. Where and what statement do I need to include in this script to get my state boundaries overlayed in the graph? I have not found an example specifically for R.

The result should look like this, just with a Basemap.

Choropleth map with state boundaries:
[image]

Many thanks in advance.

```
library(rjson)

library(plotly)


url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'

counties <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)

url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv"

df <- read.csv(url2, colClasses=c(fips="character"))

fig <- plot_ly() 

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(

    type="choroplethmapbox",

    geojson=counties,

    locations=df$fips,

    z=df$unemp,

    colorscale="Viridis",

    zmin=0,

    zmax=12,

    marker=list(line=list(

      width=0),

      opacity=0.5

    )

  )

fig <- fig %>% layout(

    mapbox=list(

      style="carto-positron",

      zoom =2,

      center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))

  )

fig
```

Comment: There is section 4.2.1 Simple features (sf) at https://plotly-r.com/maps.html#

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have tried now for several hours, but did not get states to be included in my output. Do you know how I would add them to the existing plot?

Comment: No, all I found that there is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/master/data/geojson/us-states.json but it does not show up in another choropleth trace